# Cannot update date of second datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, datepicker

I have two datepickers.

When I click date in one, I need to update minDate in second

Here is html code:

```html
<div class="search-field " data-view='return'>
        <div class="search-field-left">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="header">Från</div>
      <input type="text" name="search[legs][0][origin_text]" id="search_legs_0_origin_text" value="Stockholm (STO), Sverige" class="field-1 airport_field" placeholder="Från" data-source="/autocomplete/origin/flight" data-id-element="#search_legs_0_origin_id" />
      <input type="hidden" name="search[legs][0][origin_id]" id="search_legs_0_origin_id" value="6540299" />
      <div class="quick-destinations hide-small"><div class="quick-link" data-text="Köpenhamn (CPH), Danmark" data-id="6547676">Köpenhamn</div>, <div class="quick-link" data-text="Stockholm (STO), Sverige" data-id="6540299">Stockholm</div>, <div class="quick-link" data-text="Bangkok Don Muang (DMK), Thailand" data-id="6547002">Bangkok</div> eller <div class="quick-link" data-text="London Heathrow (LHR), England" data-id="6540398">London</div>?</div>
    </li>
    <li class="icon"><img class="right_left_arrow" data-number="0" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dzwdseno3/image/asset/right_left_arrow-c0f7e54c0a61ac009de1b92fd2ff1a4f.png" alt="Right left arrow" /></li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <div class="header">Till</div>
        <input type="text" name="search[legs][0][destination_text]" id="search_legs_0_destination_text" value="Malaga (AGP), Spanien" class="field-3 airport_field" placeholder="Till" data-source="/autocomplete/destination/flight" data-id-element="#search_legs_0_destination_id" />
        <input type="hidden" name="search[legs][0][destination_id]" id="search_legs_0_destination_id" value="6547662" />
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="show-small">
    <li>
      <div class="header">Utresedatum</div>
      <input type="text" name="search[legs][0][date_demo]" id="search_legs_0_date_demo" value="2018-04-10" class="field-1 multi_datepicker" placeholder="Resedatum" readonly="readonly" data-minDate="2018-04-06" data-maxDate="2019-04-01" data-defaultDate="2018-04-11" />
    </li>
    <li class="icon">&nbsp;</li>
    <li>
      <div class="return_fields">
        <div class="header">Hemresedatum</div>
        <input type="text" name="search[legs][1][date_demo]" id="search_legs_1_date_demo" value="2018-04-17" class="field-1 multi_datepicker" placeholder="Resedatum" readonly="readonly" data-minDate="2018-04-11" data-maxDate="2019-04-01" data-defaultDate="2018-04-18" />
        <div class="return_overlay"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="hide-small">
    <li>
      <div class="header">Utresedatum</div>
      <div id="search_legs_0_datepicker"
           data-minDate="2018-04-06"
           data-maxDate="2019-04-01"
           data-defaultDate="2018-04-11"></div>
      <input type="hidden" name="search[legs][0][date]" id="search_legs_0_date" />
    </li>
    <li class="icon">&nbsp;</li>
    <li>
      <div class="return_fields">
        <div class="header">Hemresedatum</div>
        <div id="search_legs_1_datepicker" data-minDate="2018-04-11" data-maxDate="2019-04-01" data-defaultDate="2018-04-18"></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="search[legs][1][date]" id="search_legs_1_date" />
        <div class="return_overlay"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is code for 1 datepicker

```
export function load_datepickers_inline():void {
const search_legs_0_datepicker = $("#search_legs_0_datepicker");
const leg_0_datepicker = $("#search_legs_0_datepicker").datepicker({
  // language: gon.locale,
  classes: 'inline-picker',
  altField: '#search_legs_0_date',
  defaultDate: new Date(search_legs_0_datepicker.attr("data-defaultDate")),
  minDate: new Date(search_legs_0_datepicker.attr('data-mindate')),
  maxDate: new Date(search_legs_0_datepicker.attr('data-maxdate')),
  // altFieldDateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  onSelect: (formattedDate, date, inst) => {
    if (!leg_0_datepicker) { return false; }
    leg_1_datepicker.update('minDate', date);
    if (date > leg_1_datepicker.selectedDates[0]) { leg_1_datepicker.datepicker("setDate", date); }
    if ($("#search_legs_0_hotel_date").length > 0) {
      $('#search_legs_0_hotel_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').update('minDate', date);
      $('#search_legs_0_hotel_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').datepicker("setDate", date);
      $('#search_legs_1_hotel_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').update('minDate', date);
    }
  }
})
```

When I click button, I get this error

> leg_1_datepicker.update is not a function

in this row

> leg_1_datepicker.update('minDate', date);

Here is leg_1_datepicker code

```
 const search_legs_1_datepicker = $("#search_legs_1_datepicker");
var leg_1_datepicker = $("#search_legs_1_datepicker").datepicker({
  // language: gon.locale,
  classes: 'inline-picker',
  altField: '#search_legs_1_date',
  defaultDate: new Date(search_legs_1_datepicker.attr("data-defaultDate")),
  minDate: new Date(search_legs_1_datepicker.attr('data-mindate')),
  maxDate: new Date(search_legs_1_datepicker.attr('data-maxdate')),
  // altFieldDateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  onSelect: (formattedDate, date, inst) => {
    if ($("#search_legs_1_hotel_date").length > 0) {
      $('#search_legs_0_hotel_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').update('maxDate', date);
      $('#search_legs_1_hotel_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').update('maxDate', date);
      $('#search_legs_1_hotel_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').datepicker("setDate", date);
    }
  }
})
```

Where can be my trouble?

Thank's for help

**UPDATE**

I try to fix it like this

```
leg_1_datepicker.datepicker('setDate','minDate', date);
```

But Now I have error

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Here

> if (date > leg_1_datepicker.selectedDates[0]) { leg_1_datepicker.datepicker("setDate", date); }

Comment: can you give html code?

Comment: Update my post. Check it@SupunPraneeth

Comment: you have to give me the generated html, not with the jsp code

Comment: Done, check it now@SupunPraneeth

Comment: can I confirm this: if change first datepicker data you want that select date as  second datepicker mindate right ?

Comment: yes, you're right@SupunPraneeth

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168226/discussion-between-balance-and-supun-praneeth).

Comment: take a look: https://codepen.io/spmsupun/pen/WzgvZZ

Comment: Yes, but now I get this error

`Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: in the codepen it works fine

Comment: you don't need this part: `if (date > leg_1_datepicker.selectedDates[0]) { leg_1_datepicker.datepicker("setDate", date); }`

Comment: I guess yes. Thanks@SupunPraneeth